# Quarantine questions from known poor quality users

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, new-users

*I submit this for discussion.*

It is unfair that well behaved users with real question are being outnumbered by "he's my code, fix it" questions.

I suggest a quarantine period for know bad users, nothing too draconian, say 30 minutes (possibly a sliding scale).

During this period only the user, moderators and users with a high flag weight can see the question.

The aim is to catch these question flag them (and possibly close them or edit into a decent state) before they poluite the site for other users.

If the question is fine (i.e. gets no flags etc) it will come out of quarantine and everyone can see it.

Comment: Bogging down busy SO users with crap questions makes no sense.  Downvote the question, problem solves itself.

Comment: [I already suggested something similar](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92939/i-think-stackoverflow-should-convert-to-catholicism-so-that-we-may-have-purgator), but had about as much success convincing people to sign onto the idea.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure if your feature request requires merit.

There already are low-quality filters which:

- [Reject questions from a user having a history of asking bad questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-thi)
- Reject questions having skewed code:text ratio
- Reject questions from users whose language is absymally terrible.
- Reject questions [with same title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104914/add-title-uniqueness-to-the-heuristics-for-detecting-low-quality-questions)

In addition, if a user whose post is bad does manage to get posted,

- It is automatically flagged for low quality
- There are separate queues for questions coming in from new users, answers to old questions.

In essence, most of your feature request has already been implemented

Answer (score 8):

> During this period only the user, moderators and users with a high flag weight can see the question.

While I understand why you want to "shield" the community from such questions, doing so deprives everyone of being able to evaluate the question.  Moderators are normally occupied with other duties, and will not be able to go question by question.  Also, a user with a high flag weight may possess the information or expertise to evaluate the post, but there is a much higher probability that someone within the larger community will be able to.

In short, nobody likes reading someone's junk post, but it's a responsibility we all have to bear.