# Duplicate titles for duplicate questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions, title

[Duplicate titles are now plain forbidden](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104914/add-title-uniqueness-to-the-heuristics-for-detecting-low-quality-questions). I do think that it's a good thing in most instances. But a blanket ban like this is annoying sometimes.

Case in point:

- User A posts a [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24089/returning-only-the-portion-of-a-line-after-a-matching-pattern) with a sucky title.
- User B posts a [duplicate question with a perfect title](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24140/return-only-the-portion-of-a-line-after-a-matching-pattern).

“Perfect” here means that I wanted to use user B's title on user A's question. Question A had answers while question B didn't, so I voted to close question B as a duplicate of A and not the other way round, even though question B was better worded overall. (Merging isn't an attractive option, the questions are similar enough to have similar solutions but have different example data.)

My edit to give question A the title of question B was not accepted due to the title duplication. I had no reason to edit question B, and every reason. What I ended up doing was a minor grammatical variation on the title. Is this the best we can do?

Comment: In general, it's damned irritating that the title filters apply to _edits_.

Answer (score 3):

For now it seems the best course of action is to **close the most recent question** (in this case question B) **as a duplicate of the oldest**.

People will notice that the question got closed for being a duplicate and **the ones that are interested in the subject will follow the duplicate link**, regardless of how good&clear the title of the original question is, and there they'll have the opportunity to make their contributions.