# Retrieving deleted question on stack overflow

Tags: support, status-completed, asking-questions

I asked a question on Stack Overflow, and then deleted it because it wasn't properly formatted.  I can't undelete it (not enough privilege), nor repost it (duplicate).  Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you still see it?

Comment: Thats what editting is for

Comment: No I can't - I think you need more privilege to see deleted questions

Comment: Reposting a properly formatted version should be fine.

Comment: Reposting a properly formatted version yields "duplicate"

Comment: If it was deleted, take comments you got into account and edit. If it was previously closed as a duplicate, clearly explain why it isn't.

Comment: @simchona I think Andrew was (probably) running into the [no duplicate titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104914/add-title-uniqueness-to-the-heuristics-for-detecting-low-quality-questions/106796#106796) rule, not having a problem with being closed as a duplicate

Comment: @jdarnel27 oh, thank you. Ive never run into that before so I was operating off a false premise.

Comment: @jadarnel27 I'm surprised that a deleted question was tripping that check, but it might just be a caching problem.

Comment: @AnnaLear Hmmm, good point.

Answer (score 5):

I've edited the question to fix code formatting and undeleted it. Feel free to edit it further if you think anything else needs changing.