# A (closed) question with this title already exists

Tags: bug, status-completed, title

A user has asked his question two times, the first one of which I closed.

When editing the open question, I changed the title to the one used in the closed question, and I get this message:

> a question with that title already exists; please be more specific.

I chose a different title for the time being, but: is this the intended behaviour?

Comment: Oh how I [hate that](http://so.mrozekma.com/chat-i-hate-duplicate-titles.png)

Comment: hmm, yeah we should fix this for merging..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the next build, **moderators** will be able to re-use titles from existing closed posts, for the purpose of merging questions.

Answer (score 7):

This is a somewhat recent change (September of last year):

[Add title uniqueness to the heuristics for detecting low-quality questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104914/add-title-uniqueness-to-the-heuristics-for-detecting-low-quality-questions/106796#106796)

balpha confirmed [in chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/819942#819942) that this check applies to closed questions (as you experienced), but does not apply to deleted questions.

Answer (score 1):

As jadarnel27 said, it is intended behavior, and I would like to add that any question with the same title suggests your question is a dupe of it.  A *closed* question of the same title even more strongly suggests that your question is a dupe or off-topic and will be closed for the same reason.  If you think your question is different enough to stay open, change your title to make the difference clear.