# How did this question bypass the dupe-title filter and the question rate-limit?

Tags: bug, asking-questions, rate-limiting

Here are the two questions: (10k only - since both are now deleted)

- [DVD Sorting Program for C++ Beginners (Help Needed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870765/dvd-sorting-program-for-c-beginners-help-needed)
- [DVD Sorting Program for C++ Beginners (Help Needed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870779/dvd-sorting-program-for-c-beginners-help-needed)

The titles are exactly the same - down to the letter. They were also posted two minutes apart.

How did this user get past both the duplicate title filter and the 20 minute question rate limit?

Comment: Christmas miracle?

Comment: They're deleted now, so perhaps we will never know.  Are you sure they were both from the same account?

Comment: @SamIam 10ks, mods, and developers can see deleted posts. And of course you'd need a developer to fix it anyways.

Comment: @SamIam Same account.

Comment: He posted, deleted, then reposted?

Comment: @ColeJohnson Nope. I see no deletions in the revision histories other than the most recent ones that came after I linked them here.

Comment: @Mysticial Is there a rep limit on seeing the revision history for a deleted post?

Comment: Yes, you still need 10k to see revisions. But neither of them are interesting. For both of them, the OP posts the question, it gets closed and then deleted - presumably by people pouring in from meta. For the second one, the Community user adds the duplicate link. But otherwise, that's it.

Comment: I've seen hiccups twice or thrice where the system somehow does a double-submit on the user's behalf. The posters had no idea that it had happened -- they just hit the "Post your question" button once. /cc @Asad

Comment: But they were 2 minutes apart, and the contents of the posts are not identical. (not saying the OP couldn't have ninja edited though)

Comment: @Mysticial: I don't recall the exact time spread of the earlier hiccups I've seen, but I believe there were a few minutes between. I can't find the relevant previous Meta question although I think one exists.

Comment: @Mysticial It is interesting that he posted the copy *before* his question was closed.

Comment: @Asad I suppose he posted the second one with more information in response to the comments on the first one. Of course neither version was a good question, so they both got nuked. But of course is why the server allowed it in the first place.

Answer (score 12):

The secret might be that the OP added a trailing `.` or some such character which allowed the question to go through, but was stripped from the title automatically. I haven't tested it so far, but [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104914/add-title-uniqueness-to-the-heuristics-for-detecting-low-quality-questions/106796#comment276967_106796) indicates the presence of this behavior at least as far back as September '11.

To elaborate, there is an unrelated automatic ASCII-fication of the title that occurs when you submit your question. From what Marc says [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104914/add-title-uniqueness-to-the-heuristics-for-detecting-low-quality-questions/106796#comment277190_106796), I assume the dupe check occurs on the title as it stands *before* the removal of characters, so you can add a bunch of garbage characters to make your title temporarily unique.

Needless to say, this is a bug.

Comment: But this doesn't explain the 20 minute rate limit. So there's definitely a lot more going on here.

Comment: @Mysticial I'll try to find it, but I remember someone saying the timestamp for a question is derived from the time on the person's machine. It was on a question about an answer being posted before the question, if you've seen it.

Comment: That's not possible because the rate-limit is done by ip address. So it has to be enforced on the server-end.

Comment: @Mysticial Do you think they might have forgotten to enforce account based throttling as well? A user could just use a VPN to get around it otherwise.

Comment: That's certainly possible. But we'd need a dev to confirm that. And even then, it's a loop-hole that may or may not be worth fixing.

Comment: Can this be the reason for https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/369370/terminal-prompt-not-wrapping-correctly and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105958/terminal-prompt-not-wrapping-correctly?