# How did the user post two questions with identical titles?

Tags: bug, status-review, questions, title, quality-filter

Yesterday a user posted this SO question:

[How to use JOIN to match the records in mySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74931571/how-to-use-join-to-match-the-records-in-mysql/)

Today they posted this followup question, and gave it an identical title:

[How to use JOIN to match the records in mySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74953120/how-to-use-join-to-match-the-records-in-mysql)

I thought [duplicate titles were no longer allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104914), how did they get around this check?

Comment: I thought so too, but [I was able to post a question with that title just now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74953367/how-to-use-join-to-match-the-records-in-mysql) ([link for users below 10k](https://web.archive.org/web/20221229160218/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74953367/how-to-use-join-to-match-the-records-in-mysql)), so I guess the check isn't working?

Comment: Live testing on SO is *very* risky. Some of the moderators there are *very* fast, with itchy trigger fingers. But yeah, unfortunately, this is a feature that seems to break/regress on a regular basis. Thanks for the report; hopefully someone on staff will look into it when they get back from the holiday vacation. Probably the same as [this earlier report on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/422105).

Comment: Possibly related: [I found some newly posted questions with duplicate titles. Is this a bug?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/422105)